# How to Import data to Google Sheets from password protected site using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

I am quite new to Google Apps Script, and not quite sure where to start. I am trying to import data from a password protected site. Is it possible by using **`importxml`**?

I have read similar questions recommending using Google Apps Script. But I don't know which functions to use. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Login Site: amazon.com
Username: "username"
Password: "password"
```

I am trying to pull data from the **`"Your Orders"`** tab.

Comment: This is not possible because you cannot send login credentials through `importXML` and the Amazon API does not support that request (via [Amazon](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/is-it-possible-to-get-amazon-order-details-for-users/124834))

Comment: ah, bummer. Thank you Brian for saving me time and headache trying to complete an impossible task!!